# Change rails view output from helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, handlebars.js

I have rails helpers (`hs_if`, `hs_else`):

```
= hs_if :current_user do
  Hello, {{ current_user/name }}!

  = hs_else do
    = link_to 'Sign In', sign_in_path
```

...which produces handlebars templates:

```
{{#if current_user}}
  Hello, {{ current_user/name }}!
{{else}}
 <a href="/signin">Sign In</a>
{{/if}}
```

How can I render `{{#if current_user}} ... {{else}} ... {{/if}}` without nesting `hs_else` in `hs_if`?

I think I should remove `{{/if}}` from output, but I can't find way to do it in helper.

Comment: Can you show the code for `hs_if` and `hs_else` ?

Comment: @nathanvda https://gist.github.com/1156422

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to introduce a separate method for the closing if tag (i.e. hs_endif) and remove {{/if}} part from hs_if. So that you could write something like this:

```
= hs_if :current_user do
  Hello, {{ current_user/name }}!
= hs_else do
  = link_to 'Sign In', sign_in_path
= hs_endif
```

You'll have to type a bit more, but it might make a code a bit clearer. Of course there is a danger that you forget to close your if-statement, but you'll have you unit tests to catch this anyways, right?

Comment: I hope to find something which more reliable and more similar to Haml syntax. Anyway thanks for hint :-).

Comment: Would it be an option to just write your template the way it is, no helpers needed? This way you would directly see, what your output would be.

Answer (score 0):

I think the conditional expression to check **current_user** can be used in helper (outside the mustache template):

```
module M::TemplatesHelper
  def hs_header(&block)
    if current_user
      "Hello, {{ current_user/name }}!"
    else
      link_to('Sign In', sign_in_path)
    end.html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not solution, because my example is just an example. Obliviously templates can be more complicated.

Comment: Anyway this example is JavaScript template, so I CAN'T use rails helpers in condition, because it will be rendered on front-end.